# Problem parsing html with jQuery, regex, and Firefox

Tags: jquery, regex, firefox

I am forced into parsing some HTML on the client side (and yes this really is the only option in this case), but I am having a bit of trouble in Firefox only with the following:

```
 $('#Extensions').load('/advanced/admin/config.php?type=setup&display=extensions #container li'
   ,function(){
    $('li').each(function(){

     var liRow=$(this).html();
     var reExten=/([0-9]+)/g;
     var extension = liRow.match(reExten)[0]

     var reName=/>([a-zA-z0-9\s]+ *)/g;
     var matchName = reName.exec(liRow);
     var name = matchName[1]

    });
   }
  );
```

The HTML that is being returned from `load` is something along the lines of:

```
<a href="file.php?type=A&amp;extension=1001">Test Extension &lt;1001&gt;</a>
```

The regex seems to work fine if you copy and paste it into the firefox JS console and the code as a whole works fine in internet explorer 7/8/9.

So here's the tricky bit. In firefox `matchName` is null on every other iteration of `.each`. Example output from Firebug:

```
LOG: Matches: The Boss
LOG: data: <A href="file.php?type=A&amp;extension=13">The Boss &lt;13&gt;</A>
LOG: regex: />([a-zA-z0-9\s]+ *)/g;
LOG: Matches: Test Extension
LOG: data: <A href="file.php?type=A&amp;extension=1001">Test Extension &lt;1001&gt;</A>
LOG: regex: />([a-zA-z0-9\s]+ *)/g;
LOG: Matches: John Smith
LOG: data: <A href="file.php?type=A&amp;extension=3801">John Smtih&lt;3801&gt;</A>
LOG: regex: />([a-zA-z0-9\s]+ *)/g;
LOG: Matches: Guy Smiley
LOG: data: <A href="file.php?type=A&amp;extension=3802">Guy Smiley &lt;3802&gt;</A>
LOG: regex: />([a-zA-z0-9\s]+ *)/g;
LOG: Matches: 3803
LOG: data: <A href="file.php?type=A&amp;extension=3803">Jane Doe &lt;3803&gt;</A>
LOG: regex: /extdisplay=([0-9]+)/g
LOG: Matches: 3804
LOG: data: <A href="file.php?type=A&amp;extension=3804">John Doe &lt;3804&gt;</A>
LOG: regex: />([a-zA-z0-9\s]+ *)/g;
```

Lastly, this only seems to happen when using `re.exec` and never on `str.match(re)`. I'm at a total loss and have been starting at this for an hour now so I hope the question makes some kind of sense!

Comment: I'm sure its not what you want to hear, as its not a solution to your problem: don't use regex's on HTML

Comment: If it could be avoided at all I would! The strangest part is that the regex's themselves work fine in any other browser I've tested and always when called outside of a for loop... In a word, Im stumped.

Comment: How are you generating this log output?  And why is the regex different on one of the log lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably not the final answer but its an easy thing to check.  I ran this through JSLint and got these errors.  Occasionally things like this can account for browser discrepancies.

```
Problem at line 1 character 23: Bad line breaking before ','.

$('#Extensions').load('/advanced/admin/config.php?type=setup&display=extensio...

Problem at line 7 character 45: Missing semicolon.

var extension = liRow.match(reExten)[0]

Problem at line 11 character 29: Missing semicolon.

var name = matchName[1]
```

Comment: I was unable to get this working, but thankfully I was able to get access to an API to do it all server-side!